# When editing answer after it's commented, should a notification comment be added?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

Let's say *I* answer a question. Then OP (or somebody else) comments, and *I* edit *my own* answer, should I add a comment telling that I edited it?

As I understand it, this is the only way to let other know about the edit, which they most likely will not notice otherwise. On the other hand, it seems a bit noisy to just comment `@commenter edited my answer` to get somebody notified.

I'm inclined to think that commenting is the right thing to do, but what is the community consensus or official guideline? Any finer points to consider when commenting like this?

Comment: Comment to `@ping` the OP, then delete the comment as obsolete after a reasonable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a comment is an appropriate way of notifying an OP (or someone else who has pointed out needed corrections) that you have edited your answer.

If you specify what you have changed and frame it as a response to the earlier comment, I don't see how it would constitute noise. There is a consistent narrative to the comment thread, and a reader can see how the answer changed from its original form to its final form.

It can be argued that in some cases the entire comment thread becomes obsolete once any issues have been resolved, in which case the participants can agree to purge it or flag for a moderator to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the edits, a notification is given in the top-left corner popup section.

You can see an example from my profile in the image that follows:

[image]

Comment: I think this question about notifying the OP of a *question* that an answer was edited.

Comment: That's for somebody else editing your answer. What I mean is, you yourself editing your own answer after the OP has read it, and will likely miss your edit.